# Jenkins use old build if there are not new commits on the branch

Tags: maven, github, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have some pipelines on Jenkins that are triggered every day. The scenario is very simple:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'jenkins-agent'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def mvn = tool name: 'Maven'
                    def jdk = tool name: 'openjdk-11'
                    env.JAVA_HOME = "${jdk}/amazon-corretto-11.0.18.10.1-linux-x64"
                    env.PATH = "${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${mvn}/bin:${env.PATH}"
                    sh 'java -version && mvn -version && printenv'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Checkout sources') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        echo "Check out source code \"${BRANCH}\""
                        git url: DEFAULT_REPO,
                                branch: BRANCH,
                                credentialsId: gitCredentialsID
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        echo 'Check out source code master'
                        git url: DEFAULT_REPO,
                                branch: 'master',
                                credentialsId: gitCredentialsID
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -pl MyProject -am --fail-never -DskipTests=true'
            }
        }
}
```

The build stage takes around 10 minutes and not every day there are new commits on the repo. I would like to have an option to skip build stage and use previous build if there are no changes on the repo.

[Pipeline build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gidAQ.png)

I tried to see if there is any way to use previous build but I didn't find anything on Jenkins

Answer (score 2):

From [this article](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Complete-Jenkins-Git-environment-variables-list-for-batch-jobs-and-shell-script-builds), if you are using [Jenkins Git plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/), said plugin does set [environment variables](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#plugin-content-environment-variables), including `GIT_COMMIT`.

That means you can retrieve the `GIT_COMMIT` used by the previous build, and, if unchanged, skip the current build step.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'jenkins-agent'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def mvn = tool name: 'Maven'
                    def jdk = tool name: 'openjdk-11'
                    env.JAVA_HOME = "${jdk}/amazon-corretto-11.0.18.10.1-linux-x64"
                    env.PATH = "${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${mvn}/bin:${env.PATH}"
                    sh 'java -version && mvn -version && printenv'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Checkout sources') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        echo "Check out source code \"${BRANCH}\""
                        git url: DEFAULT_REPO,
                                branch: BRANCH,
                                credentialsId: gitCredentialsID
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        echo 'Check out source code master'
                        git url: DEFAULT_REPO,
                                branch: 'master',
                                credentialsId: gitCredentialsID
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Check for changes') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.HAS_CHANGES = 'false'
                    def currentCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
                    def previousBuild = currentBuild.previousBuild
                    def previousBuildCommit = null

                    if (previousBuild != null) {
                        previousBuildCommit = previousBuild.rawBuild.getEnvironment()["GIT_COMMIT"]
                    }

                    if (previousBuildCommit == null || !previousBuildCommit.equals(currentCommit)) {
                        env.HAS_CHANGES = 'true'
                    }

                    echo "Current commit: ${currentCommit}"
                    echo "Previous build commit: ${previousBuildCommit}"
                    echo "Has changes: ${env.HAS_CHANGES}"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            when {
                expression { env.HAS_CHANGES == 'true' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -pl MyProject -am --fail-never -DskipTests=true'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If your Jenkins setup uses different agents for each build, you'll need to store the commit SHA1 in a more centralized location, so it can be accessed by any agent.

One solution is to use the [Jenkins Fingerprint feature](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/fingerprints/) to store the commit SHA1, which can then be accessed by any agent.
Another is to use a common shared path.
Another is to use a global variable throug the [build user vars](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/) plugin.

That last option would look like:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'jenkins-agent'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def mvn = tool name: 'Maven'
                    def jdk = tool name: 'openjdk-11'
                    env.JAVA_HOME = "${jdk}/amazon-corretto-11.0.18.10.1-linux-x64"
                    env.PATH = "${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${mvn}/bin:${env.PATH}"
                    sh 'java -version && mvn -version && printenv'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Checkout sources') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        echo "Check out source code \"${BRANCH}\""
                        git url: DEFAULT_REPO,
                                branch: BRANCH,
                                credentialsId: gitCredentialsID
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        echo 'Check out source code master'
                        git url: DEFAULT_REPO,
                                branch: 'master',
                                credentialsId: gitCredentialsID
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Check for changes') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.HAS_CHANGES = 'false'
                    def currentCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
                    def previousBuild = currentBuild.previousBuild
                    def previousBuildCommit = null

                    if (previousBuild != null) {
                        previousBuildCommit = previousBuild.rawBuild.getEnvironment()["LAST_COMMIT"]
                    }

                    if (previousBuildCommit == null || !previousBuildCommit.equals(currentCommit)) {
                        env.HAS_CHANGES = 'true'
                    }

                    echo "Current commit: ${currentCommit}"
                    echo "Previous build commit: ${previousBuildCommit}"
                    echo "Has changes: ${env.HAS_CHANGES}"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            when {
                expression { env.HAS_CHANGES == 'true' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -pl MyProject -am --fail-never -DskipTests=true'
            }
        }
        stage('Save commit') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.LAST_COMMIT = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you VonC, what I understand is that I need to compare the commits and there are no new commits I can use old build. The problem is that 'jenkins-agent' is always a new agent and I think the old build is no longer available on the new agent. 
For example:
First run: Agent jenkins-agent-large-2dzs3 is provisioned from template jenkins-agent-large
Second run: Agent jenkins-agent-large-r7t5f is provisioned from template jenkins-agent-large

Comment: @Nick I understand. I have edited the answer to propose an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the  git change log , if there are no changes , don't execute the build step

```
  def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
 if (changeLogSets.size() == 0) {
    println "no changes made"
   }else{
       steps {
           sh 'mvn clean install -pl MyProject -am --fail-never -DskipTests=true'
     }
 }
```

Comment: That is what chatGPT spews out: [SCM changeset](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions). But that has nothing to do with the *previous* Jenkins build, which might have been done on the same commit, with the same changeSet. You need to compare the commit of the previous build with the commit of the current build: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76172157/6309).